# Join two table with Multiple cases in ON condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I have two tables A and B and I have to perform left join on that with multiple cases in on condition.
Is there any efficient way of doing this in big query or SQL.

```
select * from table_A A
left join table_B B 

where 
[some condition OR some condition]

on   

case1       
A.column1 =B.column1
 and A.column2= B.column2
and A.column3= B.column3
and A.column4= B.column4
and A.column5= B.column5


OR case2     
A.column1 =B.column1
and A.column3= B.column3
and A.column4= B.column4
and A.column5= B.column5

OR case3   
A.column1 =B.column1
and A.column2= B.column2
and A.column4= B.column4

OR case4  
A.column1 =B.column1
and A.column3= B.column3
and A.column5= B.column5
```

Here my main motive is that for one row if my case1 matches than it will not go into other cases. Likewise it will work if first is not matches then it will check second, then third and it will get best possible one match.
Here the cases will help that to get 100% of join between A and B table.
In first cases we are checking all 5 fields of both table, but if some of the field are null than it will check other case and likewise it should work.

Comment: Sample data and desires results would help.  You should also explain what the case *conditions* are.  How do you choose which of the joins to use?

Comment: Sample data I don't have. The cases are just combination  as mentioned so that we can get 100% of match of join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the general approach in SQL is multiple `left join`s:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.col, b2.col, b3.col, b4.col) as col
from table_A A left join
     table_B B1
     on A.column1 = B1.column1 and
        A.column2 = B1.column2 and
        A.column3 = B1.column3 and
        A.column4 = B1.column4 and
        A.column5 = B1.column5 left join
     table_b B2
     on B1.column1 is null and
        A.column1 = B2.column1 and
        A.column3 = B2.column3 and
        A.column4 = B2.column4 and
        A.column5 = B2.column5 left join
     table_b B3
     on B2.column1 is null and
        A.column1 = B3.column1 and
        A.column2 = B3.column2 and
        A.column3 = B3.column3 left join
     table_b B4
     on B3.column1 is null and
        A.column2 = B4.column2 and
        A.column4 = B4.column4
```

Comment: can you please berif me about the null conditions specified in on.

Comment: @user_a27 . . . Good question.  Those simply state that the previous `join` did not find a matching row.

Comment: Now the join got matched, now I need to insert every alias B1,B2,B3,B4 columns  Into a table using the insert statement. But at a time of select I can only fetch one alias at a time.

Comment: @user_a27 . . . It sounds like you might have a new question.

Comment: Might be my question doesn't hint about insert. But yes the main issue will come at the time of writing the data. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the "best" matching B rows. I.e. if there are rows matching case 1, you want to stick with these, but if there are none, then you want to try with case 2, etc.

What you can do is combine the conditions, so as to join all possible matches first. Then look at the matches and dismiss all except the best ones. Ranking can be done with `RANK`.

```
select *
from 
(
  select 
    *,
    rank() over (partition by A.id
                 order by
                   case when A.column2 = B.column2
                         and A.column3 = B.column3
                         and A.column4 = B.column4
                         and A.column5 = B.column5 then 1
                        when A.column3 = B.column3
                         and A.column4 = B.column4
                         and A.column5 = B.column5 then 2
                        when A.column2 = B.column2
                         and A.column4 = B.column4 then 3
                                                   else 4
                   end) as rnk
  from table_A A
  left join table_B B 
    on A.column1 = B.column1
    and
    ( 
      (A.column2 = B.column2 and A.column4 = B.column4)
     or
      (A.column3 = B.column3 and A.column5 = B.column5)
    )
  where [some condition OR some condition]
) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

(My query assumes some ID in table_A. If your table doesn't have a unique ID, use whatever column(s) uniquely identify a row in the table.)

Comment: voted up - I think I see now what OP was asking for. If this is a case - make sense now. I have not checked solution itself though, so my vote is not because of code itself but because of "translating" the question and direction in answer :o)

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant: Haha, I didn't understand the question myself until I saw OP's first comment on *your* answer. And it looks like Gordon made the same guess.

Comment: so, good collaboration work for the OP's benefit  :o)

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be to use a temporary data storage (temp table, cursors, or whatever) and use a parametrized loop to feed it. The problem that you have is that in pure SQL you don't have loops. You have to use the scripting languages of bigQuery, give a look here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Answer (score 0):

Below two options I see - both for BigQuery Standard SQL (Thank you to @Thorsten-Kettner for helping in understanding OP's logic/requirements)

**Option 1** - separate joins for each case; then combine all and finally pick the winner for each record in A

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(priority, identity)
FROM (
  SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 priority, FORMAT('%t', A) identity 
      FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B
      USING(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) -- Case 1
      WHERE [SOME condition OR SOME condition]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 priority, FORMAT('%t', A) identity 
      FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B
      USING(column1,column3,column4,column5) -- Case 2
      WHERE [SOME condition OR SOME condition]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 3 priority, FORMAT('%t', A) identity 
      FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B
      USING(column1,column2,column4) -- Case 3
      WHERE [SOME condition OR SOME condition]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 4 priority, FORMAT('%t', A) identity 
      FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B
      USING(column1,column3,column5) -- Case 4
      WHERE [SOME condition OR SOME condition]
  ) t
  GROUP BY identity
)
```

**Option 1** - just pick all potential candidates in one query with on fly calculating which case the entry belong to and finally pick the winner for each row in A

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(priority, identity)
FROM (
  SELECT SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
  FROM (
    SELECT A.*, 
      B.* EXCEPT(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5),
      FORMAT('%t', A) identity 
      CASE
        WHEN (A.column1,A.column2,A.column3,A.column4,A.column5) = (B.column1,B.column2,B.column3,B.column4,B.column5) THEN 1
        WHEN (A.column1,A.column3,A.column4,A.column5) = (B.column1,B.column3,B.column4,B.column5) THEN 2
        WHEN (A.column1,A.column2,A.column4) = (B.column1,B.column2,B.column4) THEN 3
        WHEN (A.column1,A.column3,A.column5) = (B.column1,B.column3,B.column5) THEN 4
        ELSE 5
      END AS priority, 
    FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B
    ON A.column1 = B.column1 
    OR A.column2 = B.column2 
    OR A.column3 = B.column3 
    OR A.column4 = B.column4 
    OR A.column5 = B.column5 
    WHERE [SOME condition OR SOME condition]
  ) t
  WHERE priority < 5 
  GROUP BY identity
)
```

Note: above versions have similarity and different at the same time - it is matter of preferences to pick one vs another. Also wanted to note - above is not tested and just written on-fly so might need additional tunning - but most likely not  :o)